# How add Size and Position to ImageView in UITableView Cell?

Tags: swift, image, imageview, tableview, cell

I added a image to my UITableView Cell:

`cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "Default.png")`

Everything works, the image is displayed. Now I want to give a custom size and position for the image, so I try it with this code:

`cell.imageView!.frame = CGRect(x: 29, y: 17, width: 14, height: 13)`

But for any reason it doesn't work. Any advices?

Comment: You will have to subclass the UITableViewCell and design in the storyboard or create a xib file.

Comment: You mean like `cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)`?

Comment: No, In the storyboard you will have to drag and drop a tableViewCell in the tableView and add imageView and whatever u want to add.

Comment: Oh yeah, sry, I misunderstood you. Is it programmatically not possible?

Comment: you can add a uiimageview as a subview but that might cause some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your position will not change You can create frame in your `TableViewCell`

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: 23, width: 12, height: 100)
}
}
```

You can change frame in `tableview(cellForRowAt)` but If frame will not change its a bad because `cellForRowAt` run when scrolling up - down or loading cell . You can define in UITableViewCell once.

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct answer. The `layoutSubviews` was the key.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a custom class for this custom tableViewCell.
2. Create a custom tableViewCell inside the tableView through the storyboard.
3. Add image inside this custom tableViewCell.
4. Add constraints (top, bottom, leading, trailing) to this image.

This way, you won't have to do anything programmatically and the image size issues will be taken care of by these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

- It'd be better if you do that frame related things in **storyboard** or **Xib** files itself. if you want them with static frame.

RunTime:

- You can use **NSLayoutConstraints**
- You can change the frame in **draw(_ rect: CGRect)** method.